# Adding Google Mobile Interstitial Ads Swift

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I want to add Google Mobile Interstitial Ads, and I'm getting errors. How can I add Google Interstitial Ads?

Here's what I have so far:

```
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

func createAndLoadAd() -> GADInterstitial
{
    var ad = GADInterstitial()
    ad.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-5378899862041789/8532100959"

    var request = GADRequest()

    ad.loadRequest(request)

    return ad
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code for interstitial :

Import `GoogleMobileAds` Framework and Set Delegates to View :

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate
```

Declaration :

```
var interstitial:GADInterstitial?
```

Function :

```
//Interstitial func
func createAndLoadInterstitial()->GADInterstitial {
    var interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-5378899862041789/8532100959")
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.loadRequest(GADRequest())
    
    return interstitial
}
```

Function Call :

```
interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
```

Add delegate methods to load ad.

**Add other frameworks that the SDK requires**

The SDK depends on the following iOS development frameworks which may not already be part of your project:

```
AdSupport
AudioToolbox
AVFoundation
CoreGraphics
CoreMedia
CoreTelephony
EventKit
EventKitUI
MessageUI
StoreKit
SystemConfiguration
```

For the updated options please follow this steps provided by [Google](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start).

Comment: I'm still geting errors.                                                                               var interstitial = GADInterstitial() //'init' is unavaliable Use initWithAdUnitID                                                                                                    _                                                                                            interstitial.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-5378899862041789/8532100959" //Cannot assign to 'adUnitID' in 'Interstitial'

Comment: I couldn't becuase I don't have enough reputations.

Comment: no longer works with Google Mobile Ads version 8

Comment: @softwareisfun yeh! because it's very old question and very old answer :D Check updated link.